# Trust anchor for certification path not found on Android 5.x and 4.x w. Let's Encrypt on server

Tags: android, ssl, android-volley, lets-encrypt

I ran into an issue with my App which is well-known: java exception on SSL handshake "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found".

The HTTP request is done with Volley

My problem is that I cannot really understand what happened - my App has not been updated since March this year and back in that time everything was Ok. The certificate is also valid, no changes on the back-end have been done.

Moreover, exactly same App works w/o any problem on Android 8 and higher (I have not checked on 6 and 7 as I do not have a proper device)

Is there any idea what can be wrong on older versions of Android with this issue and how to solve it?...

URL: [Site here](https://fellow7000.com)

p.s. I tried both, with "https://www" and w/o "www", both not working on Android 5.0 and below

Thanks & Regards!

Comment: *"The certificate is also valid, no changes on back-end has been done."* - given that Let's Encrypt certificate are only valid for 3 month it is unlikely that no changes have been done. At least the certificate would not to be updated and maybe something went wrong here, like skipping an essential intermediate certificate only required on these old devices (which might not have the Let's Encrypt root certificate). You might check your site yourself with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and if you don't see anything there it might help to provide the URL in your question.

Comment: @Steffen Thanks for feedback. Certificate was renewed couple of times, last time today as one of the probably cause. After last renewal in October everything was working. Thy only problem I see with SSLLabs is DNS CAA is "No" in my case. Updated question with URL

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that the Let's Encrypt root CA "ISRG Root X1" is not part of the trust store on these old Android devices. You can check this by visiting https://valid-isrgrootx1.letsencrypt.org/ from inside your application on these devices - if it fails the root CA is not there.

To make the validation work in this case without changes on the devices you can provide a different intermediate certificate by the server, i.e. [this CA certificate for Let's Encrypt Authority X3](https://censys.io/certificates/25847d668eb4f04fdd40b12b6b0740c567da7d024308eb6c2c96fe41d9de218d) which was issued by DST Root CA X3 instead of [your currently provided certificate for Let's Encrypt Authority X3](https://censys.io/certificates/731d3d9cfaa061487a1d71445a42f67df0afca2a6c2d2f98ff7b3ce112b1f568) which was issued by ISRG Root X1.

For more information see [the SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=fellow7000.com) and look for the second certification path which requires an extra download.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Do you have any idea why it had been working before with these phone and now not anymore?..

Comment: @Fellow7000: Maybe you've changed the certificate chain you serve when renewing the Let's Encrypt certificates.

Comment: might be, have no clue in the moment, I'm not that familiar with SSL, so will need to investigate deeper... Is there any way to check which SSL are accepted by older Android?.. Probably the better option would be to buy a normal one and forget about renewal every 3 months

Comment: @Fellow7000: You can run into similar problems with other (what you call "normal" of unknown reason) certificates too. The problem is not that you have to renew it often but you can screw the setup up when renewing - so you better have some established process for this which includes testing. I don't think that there is a reliable place to check which CA are trusted by various Android versions since this not only depends on the Android version but also on the vendor providing updates, customer installing updates, maybe browser vs. app etc.

Comment: By the way, finally with the tech. support of Let's Encrypt this issue was found on the hosting side, but they declined it, saying they follow all modern standards. Finally I had to migrate to another certificate which solved my problem.

Comment: @Fellow7000: *"... saying they follow all modern standards ..."* - I would assume that this is actually true. What is not following modern standards though are devices which still run such outdated and no longer supported versions of Android though. This is like still running Windows XP.

Comment: I would not say so - the problem was even with Android 7.0, which is 2-3 year-old devices. Not old at all. The real issue is a short life-cycle of Android Updates vs. iOS